# Displaying a view in two ways (push and modally)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboardsegue

I'm using a storyboard. I have a `UINavigationController`, with a `UITableViewController` as its `rootViewController`. From this table view, the user can access the `DetailViewController` (a custom `UIViewController` subclass) in two ways:

1. tap a table cell to view its information
2. tap the plus button to create a new item

For way 1, I want my segue to be pushed. For way 2, I want the details to be displayed modally.

At first I thought this shouldn't be too difficult, but I was opposed with some trouble. What caused this trouble: the navigation bar. When the next view is pushed, the navigation bar is there. When the next view is displayed modally, however, the navigation bar isn't there.

I know that Apple has thought about this and this is the most logical approach, but I need the navigation bar in my modal view to dismiss the modal view again (using a cancel and a done button). Adding this navigation bar through interface builder brings no luck: for the modally displayed view it works fine, but in my pushed view, I suddenly have two navigation bars.

The logical solution to this would be to add the navigation bar programmatically, *only* if the view is displayed modally. I did this, and the navigation bar was displayed, but it overlapped the view. I tried resizing my view so it has the same size as the view that's being pushed, but I did not manage to solve the problem: the navigation bar was still overlapping the view.

There are two reasons I stopped trying at this point: I didn't know what to try anymore, and I felt like there should be a much easier way, as I'm probably not the only one trying to achieve this.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Why is it important to present the same view controller from the same table in two different ways? Seems like pushing the v.c. onto the navigation stack would make sense whether editing an existing item or creating a new one.

Comment: That's of course a possibility, but I felt like it's more natural to present it modally when creating a new item. I'm not gonna change my mind just because I don't get it to work right away.

Comment: I posted as a comment because changing the design doesn't answer the question, but I think you should reconsider. The new item button you described doesn't seem to fit [the criteria for modal presentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/UEBestPractices/UEBestPractices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH20-SW24). It's hard to see what additional benefit the user gets from two different presentations. Unifying the two cases will make your app seem less complicated. And if it happens to be easier to implement too, that's good, right?

Comment: I understand what you're saying, and I also think it's very important that the presentations used in an app need to make perfect sense. I think that a modally presented view for adding a new item *does* fit, because the user has to save or cancel it explicitly. I don't think the app would be too complicated when using these two presentation styles for the same view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another navigation controller with your detail view controller as its root view controller. Then present that new navigation controller modally using your main view controller as the presenter.

Comment: That's not as elegant as I hoped it would be, but at least it works. ;-)